# SQL For each row execute command

Tags: mysql, sql, foreach, row

I want to iterate through a mysql table and for each row I want to execute a command with the ID of the current row.

So in simple code this needs to be done:

```
FOR EACH ROW IN TABLE
SQL -> "UPDATE TABLE SET Value= '5' WHERE ID='ROW_ID'"
END FOR
```

I've looked on the internet but I encountered very vague answers.
Can somebody help me with the SQL Command I need to use? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `update`:

```
UPDATE TABLE t
    SET Value = '5'
```

This will update all rows in the table.  Use the `where` statement only when you want to filter the rows being updated.

Comment: Well in my case it isn't that easy.
For each ID I need to "COPY" data from another table with the same ID.

Comment: Do you maybe have an idea how to do this?

Comment: @DaniëlStekelenburg . . . You should ask another question, providing sample data and desired results.  This question (where the same table provides the values and is being modified) already has several answers.  If you change the question, then you invalidate the answers -- which is impolite.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting this ,

UPDATE TABLE t
    SET Value = (select row_id from another_table)

You can use other table data.

Comment: Ehm Well yeah but I do need to get the row id for each row.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using this code:

```html
UPDATE wWEEK JOIN STANDARD ON STANDARD.ID = wWEEK.ID SET 
 wWEEK.Column1 = STANDARD.Column1,
 wWEEK.Column2 = STANDARD.Column2,
 wWEEK.Column3 = STANDARD.Column3,
 wWEEK.Column4 = STANDARD.Column4,
 wWEEK.Column5 = STANDARD.Column5,
 wWEEK.Column6 = STANDARD.Column6
```